# Repository error - The context cannot be used while the model is being created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting the following exception when trying to retrieve data from my registry:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   OHR.Repository.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The context cannot be used while the model is
>   being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used
>   inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is
>   accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members
>   of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

This error occurs on the first database query that I'm running in the method called MovieExists:

MovieRepository.cs:

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

public MovieRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    this._context = context;
}

public bool MovieExists(string MovieUrl)
{

    try
    {
        bool result;
        using (_context)
        {
            // The next line causes the exception
            result = _context.Movies.Any(p => p.Url == MovieUrl);
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

My context.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

}
```

I'm using EF6, and while I have async EF tasks, this very first one is not using any async calls so I don't think I'm trying to use the context on multiple threads.

I assume I'm not instantiating the context properly, but can't see how to fix the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, the problem was that I made the ApplicationDbContext _context readonly.  Removing readonly fixed the issue.

Comment: That shouldn't have been the problem if you are only reading (ie:  _context.Movies.Any). Typically with the repo pattern readonly DbContext is declared from the uow and you inject the uow into the repo to persist data using an internal reference.